# How show google play store info of my mobile app at web site

Tags: android, wordpress

My client have a mobile app and I want to show google play store info like, rating, stars, votes and  comments at a wordpress site.

I don't want  to give play store link like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xxx

How can I realize it?

Comment: This depends on what you want to to, is it an iframe with some content? There should be plenty of them out there.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to search plugins here: [wordpress.org/plugins/](https://wordpress.org/plugins/)

- Found https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-play-store-badge/ - Maybe you can use this plugin?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I found this plugin which scraps some data from google play store web site.  https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-web-scrapper/